# Wordpress: How to combine header title using wp_title() and the site name

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a question regarding WP header title. 
The script below shows the page title

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
//Books
```

Now I would like to combine it with the website name like this

**Books | Mywebsitename**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have set site title in word press admin setting >> general >> site title
then use below code.

```
wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ).' '. bloginfo('name');
```